# Please explain me the working of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

```
x = 10 
def func(num):
    x = 5 
    for i in num:
        x*= i
    return x
print(func((-2,-1,1,2,3)))
```

Please explain me why the answer is 60 for this. How is for loop is working in this?

Comment: What about it don't you understand? `x` starts off as 5, is multiplied by each of the elements of the tuple in `num`, and ends up as 60 because `5 * -2 * -1 * 1 * 2 * 3 = 60`

Comment: [Don't include code as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). [Formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: Any introductory book on Python should cover the basics of looping very early on.

Comment: `x*= i` is shorthand for `x = x * i`. Does that help? If you put a print statement in each loop iteration it may give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: A great way to figure out algorithms is to take a pencil and paper and then trace through it by hand. Write down how the variables change in each line. You'll get a feel for how algorithms work and it'll be easier to do it in your head the next time.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `func()` with a tuple `(-2,-1,1,2,3)`.

If you loop over a tuple with `for i in a_tuple:`, `i` will assume each value of the tuple in turn.

So, in your case, `x` starts out as `5` and then gets multiplied by every value in the `num` tuple that was passed as an argument to `func()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function, you pass in the tuple (-2,-1,1,2,3).

Within that function, you do a few things. First, you assign the value 5 to the variable x. Then, you loop over the elements in that tuple, assigning each one in turn to the variable i. Each time, you multiply the value of x by the value of i. Once this is complete, you return the value of x.

So, when you do this, you multiply 5 by the value of the first value of the tuple (-2), giving you -10 as the value of x, then you multiply it by the second value of the tuple (-1) giving x a value of 10, and then you similarly multiply it by 1, then by 2, then by 3, for a final value of 60.